# How to install a nuget package from github actions

Tags: .net, github, nuget, github-actions, nuget-package

I've been trying to use GitHub actions to automate package updation from one repo to the next. I currently have a repo on which a new release will be made and i want to take that new package to the next repo (using as a dependency).

repo 1 -> release -> repo 2 -> install.

I have set up a trigger and wait workflow but the triggered workflow is supposed to install the package from repo 1's release.

It seems as though the workflow is executing but when i check package.config, i can still see that it's not updated to the latest release from repo 1.

```
name : Install Latest Core Package
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - SOF-4565-AutomatePackageUpdate
env: 
  ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS : true

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:  
      - name: Setup .NET Core SDK
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3.0.2
      
      - name: Nuget Add Source
        run: nuget sources Add -Name github -Source PATH -UserName USER -Password ${{ secrets.NUGET_TOKEN }}
      
      - name: Core package update
        run: dotnet nuget add source PATH -n github -u ${{ github.actor }} -p ${{ secrets.NUGET_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text
```

I have tried with this .yml file. Is there something that I'm missing?

EDIT :
[image]

This is the only change I see in logs when I do the required action locally

[image]

On github, when i run "nuget install PACKAGE" It's adding the packages to the root but its not updating the config file. I'd like to update the package.config and add the package files to the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

In your yaml file I observe that you only added nuget source, later you need to bump the package and commit to git

```yaml
- name: Bump Package
  run: |
     dotnet add package <package_name> --version ${{ needs.PublishPackages.outputs.buildVersion }}
     git commit -a -m "Bump to ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}" -m "Version <githubusername_orgname>/<nuget_package_repo_name>@${{ needs.PublishPackages.outputs.sha7 }}"
     git push
```

I had similar requirement, incase if you want you read in [detail](https://blog.dchennaraidu.com/automate-net-nuget-package-using-github-actions#heading-final-workflow-file)

Comment: I'm getting this error in my action when i run dotnet add package : 
`/home/runner/work/VSDaVinci/VSDaVinci`
and yes, this is where my package.config and VSDaVinci.csproj is

Comment: Is your `package.config` in the folder or in root folder? Try to debug GH action by listing all the files in that folder `ls -la`, and strongly suggest to upgrade to [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) if possible

Comment: So I tried doing the same update package from VS2019 and in the git log i can only see that the package.config has the new package updated from previous. I do not see any new dll added as part of the build. Do you know how we can do the same in github actions?